# Is this the correct way to save a pointer to an upper layer object in Python?

Tags: python

I am using python to implement an application. I have following classes:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self._B_list=[]    # objects of B class will be appended as the application run
        b = B(self)        # I use A as initial parameter of B
        self._B_list.append(b)


class B()
    def __init__(self, A_object):
        self._parent = A_object      # Here I save the pointer of upper layer class object
```

As you can see from above, class `A` has a list of objects of class `B`. And `B` will record its upper layer object. The reason I do this is because there is a big data container (20 MB) in class `A`, and it should be shared by all the class `B` objects in its list.

I think the way I showed above is memory effective. But since I've never been formally traind to code Python, I am not very sure about this. So may I have you opinion? Any comments are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how strong the connection is, maybe this is an alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python ?

Comment: Are there several instance of A or only one ?

Comment: @hivert There's only one A object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is only one A, you don't need to store a pointer to it in every single instance of B. Once this `OnlyOneA` is created, just assign it to **the class** `B` and every instance of B will find it:

```
class A(): 
    def __init__(self):
        assert(not hasattr(B, '_parent')) # make sure there is only one A
        B._parent = self
        ...
```

then if `myB` is an instance of `B`

```
my._parent
```

will get the instance of A.

Comment: Hi, hivert. Thanks for the answer. Sounds very reasonable. On the other hand, may I know what is the memory usage in my way? Will the `OnlyOneA` be duplicated for each `B` and practically occupy a memory block?

Comment: No it won't. It's only stored in the class as a reference (no copy). It's called a *class attribute*